# How to use special character in outfile delimiter in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am exporting a set of rows into a .csv outfile using mysql. However I want fields to be delimited by

```
End of Text (ETX/ASCII 03)
```

instead of  `,` . Please let me know, how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it. I used FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'03';